# Third submenu not appearing inline with selected menu in secondary submenu

Tags: html, css, menu, submenu

I've got a menubar with just plain HTML and CSS and need three submenus to branch out. When you run what I've got the first two submenus form in-line with whatever menu option is being hovered over, but the third always appears at the top of the secondary submenu. I cannot find what ties the third to the top of the secondary menu. Any ideas?

**note: I refer to the menu as the third submenu but in the CSS it is called fourth-level-menu

HTML

```
<ul class="top-level-menu">
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Offices</a>
        <ul class="second-level-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Chicago</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Los Angeles</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">New York</a>
                <ul class="third-level-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Information</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Book a Meeting</a></li>
                    <li>
                      <a href="#">Testimonials</a>
                      <ul class="fourth-level-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Seattle</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
/* Menu Styles */

.fourth-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.fourth-level-menu > li
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.fourth-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.third-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.third-level-menu > li
{
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.third-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.second-level-menu
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    left: 0;
    width: 150px;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: none;
}

.second-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    height: 30px;
    background: #999999;
}
.second-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu
{
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.top-level-menu > li
{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    width: 150px;
    background: #999999;
}
.top-level-menu > li:hover { background: #CCCCCC; }

.top-level-menu li:hover > ul
{
    /* On hover, display the next level's menu */
    display: inline;
}


/* Menu Link Styles */

.top-level-menu a /* Apply to all links inside the multi-level menu */
{
    font: bold 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;

    /* Make the link cover the entire list item-container */
    display: block;
    line-height: 30px;
}
.top-level-menu a:hover { color: #000000; }
```

Thanks, Jake

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it's your:

```
.fourth-level-menu
 {
  top: 0px;
 }
```

If you change the `top` property to `60px` it works for me.

Hope this could help you.

EDIT

Ok got it now. You must set the position of the third-level-menu li to relative:

`.third-level-menu > li {
  position: relative;
}`

Now if you add fourth-level options, they will be shown next to the `:hover` option in the third-level-menu.

Hope this is what you searched for.

Comment: This only sets it to be flush with the lower menu option, I need it to automatically stem out of the location next to whichever submenu option is hovered over like the third-level-menu does for the second-level-menu.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you so much!